# Ruby on Rails nested attributes not saving into database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm trying to create a list of items within a "Todo list", however, I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly with nested attributes. I think using a nested attribute is the right attempt because there's going to be a large list of items, and it will be associated with the correct "Todo list" based on ids.

Example of what the tables ***might*** look like when records are populated

**Todo table**

```
id         list       
1          grocery shopping
2          health insurance
```

**Item table**

```
id         todo_id        name           
1          1              buy milk
2          1              buy cereal
3          2              Blue Shield
4          2              Healthnet
5          1              buy cherries
```

---

Although, with my attempt below, my application is not saving any of the data into the `Item` database.

**Todo Controller**

```
class TodoController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
    @todo.items.build
  end
end
```

**Todo Model**

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

**Item Model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :todo
end
```

**Todo View**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@todo) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :list %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |g| %>
    <%= g.input :name %>
  <% end%>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I was able to have the `name` field show up in my view, but when I save it, it doesn't save into the database, however, I'm able to save the list into the database, and then when I try to edit the record, the `name` field doesn't show up anymore to be able to edit.

---

**EDIT: to show create method**

This is my current Create Method in Todo Controller

```
def create
  @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @todo.save
      format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure if Edit needs to have something, but I only have this from generating a scaffold of Todo

```
def edit
end
```

---

**EDIT 2** show todo_params

```
def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:user_id, :list)
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'fields_for :items'?

Comment: @AJFaraday oops, you're right. I don't know why I wrote that... it mustve been the television that I'm watching... Thanks!

Comment: Okay, the TodosController needs a create method. If it has one, it may help to include it in the question. Also, what does the log look like when you're submitting the form? Does it go to TodosController#create? Does the :todo hash inlude an arribute called "items"?

Comment: I've just seen your comment, did that solve the issue?

Comment: @AJFaraday no, that didn't solve the issue. Also, I updated my post to show create method. My log shows that it goes to #create, and it inserts into the `todo` table, but I don't see any insert into `item` table

Comment: Did you whitelist the items attributes in `todo_params` method ? (including the id param)

Comment: Please show your `todo_params` code :D

Comment: Also a suggestion, I believe your TODO list isn't meant to be empty ? `validates :items, :length => {:minimum => 1, :message=>"At least one item TODO" }`

Comment: Have you called items_attributes: [:name] in your todo_params?

Comment: todo_params should be defined in your controller.

Comment: @hellomello `todo_params` must be the name of a private method in your `todo_controller.rb` ^^. If it's not there, your code should crash when it calls `todo_params`

Comment: @CyrilDD thanks! I updated my post to show todo_params. Should I have `:name` in there? I'll add those validates! Thank you :)

Comment: yep. like so.... params.require(:todo).permit(:user_id, :list, items_attributes: [:name])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add the nested params to your strong params

```
def todo_params
  params.require(:todo).permit(:user_id, :list, items_attributes: [:id, :text, ...])
end
```

**Note** about todo_id :

You don't need to add `:todo_id` in `items_attributes` list, because you already have the TODO as context.

```
@todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
```

In the above code, your todo_params will contain some item_attributes linked to `@todo`. ie, it's similar to doing

```
@todo.items.build
```

It will already create an item with a `todo_id` corresponding to `@todo.id`

Comment: Thanks for your help! How do I pass the parameters to ensure that it will save the id into `todo_id`? Is adding `:todo_id` enough? or am I supposed to do something like `:todo_id => {params[:id]}` or something? This might be wrong syntax...

Comment: Don't worry about this, you are adding **nested** attributes, so the items are already added under the context of a "Todo" (the `todo_id` is somewhat transferred to child items). The ID  in `items_attributes` makes sure you can edit your items instead of creating new ones each tme ;-)

Comment: Okay cool thanks! Yeah I tried it, and it automatically saved it... Last question: If I didn't have a `todo_id` in my ITEM table, will this not work? I must have a relationship id to make this work right?

Comment: You are right. This what is expected when you write `belongs_to :todo`. With ActiveRecord, you need to manually synchronize your models with your database schema (migrations, etc. to make sure there's a `todo_id` column). If you try other DBs like MongoDB/Mongoid, your model becomes exactly your DB structure, without any need for migrations (and I find this wonderful tbh)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the items to the list of whitelisted attributes

```
def todo_params
 params.require(:todo).permit(
   :user_id, 
   :list,
   items_attributes: [ # you're missing this
     :id,
     :name
   ]
 )
end
```